# Hibernate sends NULL for autogenerated field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have entity described as

```
@Entity(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
```

it's table is created by Hibernate with

```
Hibernate: create table my_entity (id integer generated by default as identity,
```

i.e. it knows that field is autogenerated. Despite that having code

```
private MyEntity storeNewMyEntity(String fqn) {
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.setFullyQualifiedName(fqn);
    return myEntityDao.save(myEntity);
}
```

it translates it into

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "id"; SQL statement:
insert into my_entity (id,
```

Why and how to fix?

Dialect is

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `hibernate-core` jar to 5.6.5.Final or any later version, current version in 5.6 branch is 5.6.7.Final and 6.0.0.Final is also already available.

Older versions don't support new versions of H2.